# No Enum constant found for type in java

Tags: java, enums

I am using `enum` in java, Here is the enum

```
public enum AbuseSectionType{

    MUSIC("Music"), DANCE("Dance"), SOLO("Solo"), ACT("Act")

    private String displayString;

    AbuseSectionType(String displayValue) {
        this.displayString = displayValue;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getDisplayString() {
        return displayString;
    }

    public void setDisplayString(String displayString) {
        this.displayString = displayString;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get value `AbuseSectionType.valueOf("Music")`. I am getting no enum constant and found no error. I am supposed to have value `MUSIC`.

Comment: Correct. MUSIC is not Music. Even though it has a `String` field with that value.

Comment: the `valueOf` method in `enum` types is case sensitive!

Comment: @Elliot Frisch How do get MUSIC if I have Music String.

Comment: [`AbuseSectionType.valueOf("Music".toUpperCase())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--)

Answer (score 5):

The `name()` of an enum is the name specified when declaring it, `MUSIC` in your case.

If we read the javadoc for `valueOf()`:

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name.

`valueOf()` is using the `name()` of the enum. But what you want to achieve is different, so you cannot use this method. What you can do instead is to make your own method that finds the value from your own field (`displayString`).

Here's an example:

```
public static AbuseSectionType fromDisplayString(String displayString)
{
    for(AbuseSectionType type : AbuseSectionType.values())
        if(type.getDisplayString().equals(displayString)
            return type;

    return null; //not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `valuOf()` method will only retrieve the respective `enmum` if the exact spelling of the enum-definition is used. In your case you have defined the enum `MUSIC` so in order to get that one you have to do it like this: `AbuseSectionType.valueOf("MUSIC");`

In order to achieve what you seem to want you have to implement a method in the enum class by yourself. For your example you could do somthing like this:

```
public AbuseSectionType resolve(String name) {
    for(AbuseSectionType current : AbuseSectionType.values()) {
        if(current.displayString.equals(name)) {
            return current;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `AbuseSectionType.valueOf("MUSIC")` pass the name of enum. See java docs regarding use of valueOf

Comment: In case you want to get displayString then use AbuseSectionType.MUSIC.getDisplayString()